# I want to Sort spreadsheet by using Header value (Column name) and not Column number

Tags: google-apps-script

In my spreadsheet, there is a column which contains "Date Time" values like 15-02-2019 05:10. I have inserted a new Blank Column ahead of this column and by using "Split Text to Column" function, have transported the time values in this new column.

Now, my spreadsheet looks like this -

[image: Present data]

Now, when I am trying to Sort this spreadsheet by using the Column No of "Time Since" Column (Column No 04), I am getting random data.

Code used - r.sort([{column: 4, ascending: false}]);

Please guide me so that I can Sort my data by using Header value "Time Since" instead of Column No. Thanks

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. Make a [mcve] and include it in your question.

Comment: I am trying to achieve my objective by Split Text to Column function and then by sorting through a Column. Thanks to S.L.Barth for the prompt interest. Since I am new to this wonderful platform, I will keep his advice in mind next time before posting.

Comment: You're welcome! [Edit] what you've attempted into your question. You may want to include what happens when you use Split Text to Column and then sort by Column. Good luck!

Comment: I have further edited/updated my question now. Thanks again

Comment: There are some libraries out there that are much easier to use than messing with Ranges and indexes. Check out --> http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gassnips/fiddler